# Reload UITableView has UITableViewCell visibility issue

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView with two row. First row have the UITextField and second row have the UICollectionView. On reloading the UITableView, cell of UICollectionViewCell does not appear.But on scrolling the UITableView all cell of UICollectionView becomes visible. What wrong I might be doing.

```
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cellIdentifier = "NewPostCell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? NewPostCell
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = Utils.getCellForGivenIdentifier(cellIdentifier, cellIdentifier: cellIdentifier, ownerT: self) as? NewPostCell
        }
        cell?.txtPost.delegate = self

        cell?.txtPost.text = userThoughts


        newPostCell = cell
        return cell!
    } else {

        let cellIdentifier = "ASAttachmentCell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? ASAttachmentCell
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = Utils.getCellForGivenIdentifier(cellIdentifier, cellIdentifier: cellIdentifier, ownerT: self) as? ASAttachmentCell
        }

        if let height = cell?.collectionAttachment?.contentSize.height
        {
            cell?.cntCollectionHeight.constant = height
        }

        attachmentCell = cell
        return cell!
    }




    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         if indexPath.row == 1 {
             attachmentCell = cell as? ASAttachmentCell
             attachmentCell?.attachmentCollection(self)
            }
   }
```

Comment: The same thing happened both in device simulator and real device?

Comment: yes it is happing on device and simulator both

Comment: Can you put some code about cellforrowattheindexpath and collectionView datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in your code, exactly to the part where you set the collection view datasource also a :

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you are calling `tableView.reloadData()` on a background thread. Therefore, when you actually begin to scroll, the UI will get updated on the main thread and everything will look normal. Try calling the reloading on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```